# Add char array to LoadLibrary

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I need to load a dll using a static library i know how to load the dll but I can't workout how to add my character array to load library. I have tried using a for loop but it wouldn't run inside the load library brackets. I can't use a string because it's against the specification I have been given.

```
int PlayARound(int &score, int &numAsked, char roundName[])
{
    HINSTANCE hinstLib;
    getQuesPnt ProcAdd;
    BOOL fFreeResult, fRunTimeLinkSuccess = FALSE;

    hinstLib = LoadLibrary();
}
```

I should say that this is homework so I am not looking for a complete solution just to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: _Static_ library? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes i have to load a dll from a static libaray

Comment: What do you mean "from a static library". Please don't just repeat the same phrase again.

Comment: Anyway, did you read the documentation on `LoadLibrary` in order to discover how to use it?

Comment: phrase "how to add my character array to load library" makes no sense

Comment: The problem you might be experiencing is that the build is targeting UNICODE, which means `LoadLibrary()` is actually `LoadLibraryW()` which expects a wide string as its argument but `roundName` is not. You could use `LoadLibraryA()` explicitly, if you are permitted.

Comment: I am using visual studio and inside my solution I have a main program and a static library I have to run this function from a static library in my main program and that will then load any dll I pass to it heres the function call we have been given 'PlayARound(score, numAsked, "demo.dll");'

Comment: Why do you want to put the char array into LoadLibrary? The brackets shuold contain the name of the dll you want to load.

Comment: @aleguna I need to add the contents of my char array as the dll files name

Comment: @bobthemac, the dll file name is supplied as an argument to `LoadLibrary()`. Nothing else to it.

Comment: declare your function argument as `LPCTSTR roundName` and then just pass it to `LoadLibrary`. Also it's good style to use `TEXT` macro with string literals to be unicode agnostic, i.e. `PlayARound(score, numAsked, TEXT("demo.dll"))`

Comment: @StevieG the char array contains the name of the dll i need to load because there are going to be multiple dlls with the same functions.

Comment: @aleguna I can't do that because it is against the specification I have been given i have to use a char array

Comment: @bobthemac, well then tell your tutor that he's an idiot. And use a type cast `hinstLib = LoadLibrary((LPCTSTR)roundName);`

Comment: @aleguna Thanks that worked perfectly add it as an answer bellow and ill mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was discovered in comments all you need is cast your array to `LPCTSTR`

```
hinstLib = LoadLibrary((LPCTSTR)roundName);
```

However the proper way would have been to change the declaration

```
int PlayARound(int &score, int &numAsked, LPCTSTR roundName);
```

and then use `TEXT` macro to make your program unicode aware

```
PlayARound(score, numAsked, TEXT("demo.dll"));
```

Comment: I'm waiting for the first people to point out how Unicode is the only thing you need to care for these days and how this is obsolete. +1

Comment: Saying that you can simply cast the `char[]` to `LPCTSTR` is just plain wrong. If `UNICODE` is enabled, `LPCTSTR will map to `LPCWSTR`, which is `wchar_t*` and thus not compatible with `char[]`, so a simple type-cast will not work. Changing the parameter from `char[]` to `LPCTSTR` is correct, though.